# Router firmware upgrades- are they worth it?

Tags: router

I'm aware this question is fairly vague, and I will try and give as much context as possible.

My router is pretty old. I don't know exactly how old, but we're talking about something like 5-7 years. It allows a maximum of 4 connections at a time, which is fine under ordinary circumstances, but when I come home from college, we pretty consistently have issues with being at the limit and not being able to connect things. Super annoying.

This is a Netgear router, model WPN82 4v2, firmware version V2.0.10_1.2.17NA. The current version is 2.0.26, so I'm definitely far behind. My questions are:

1) Will upgrading firmware change the maximum number of allowed connections?
2) Will my current settings remain the same/will devices that can currently connect to it be able to afterwards, without tons of hassle?
3) What benefits/losses can I expect out of upgrading?

Thanks a lot, please let me know if I need to offer more information.

Comment: Honestly you might as well just get a new one. Their dirt cheap, a good one will run you maybe $50

Comment: Upgrading the firmware will not change the physical limitations of the router.  The settings should remain the same but create a backup.  Read the changlog for the firmware in question.

Comment: Note 2.0.10 vs 2.0.26 is not really a big difference. The major versioning is the same, as well as the minor. Most likely any differences are bug fixes, tweaks or UI related and not to change the functionality of the router.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the firmware upgrade will do what you are looking for. I would get another one too as Simon suggests. The "N" version allows almost double the range in distance and data rate. There is an AC version out from what I can see but that is a newer standard and will come at a higher price, about $120 USD. This is will get you where you need to go.  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0AT1802404

Comment: Whatever firmware you flash your router to, you will still have a "G" version router. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11  Here is a link that shows all the standards. A lot of it is greek to me, but to look at the differences in distances and MIMO the "N" version looks like it will carry multiple users as you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you find your router is not behaving as it should, then I would flash to the latest firmware.  It may be the issue has been resolved in a newer version.

I would go ahead and upgrade to the new version.  Its free and it would only take a few minutes of your time.  Best case, everything is fixed.  Although extremely unlikely, the worst case is you brick the router.  If the worst case *were* to happen, then just buy a new router, they are cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Its sort of a relative question. It depends. I have a D-Link and the firmware was
outdated. On top of that, my desktop needed to have its virus defintions updated
and it wouldn't/couldn't connect through the local connection.

My laptop was still connecting to the access point and was working. The problem 
was that the firmware that was shipped wouldn't go past the year 2012. So it 
wasn't synced up correctly.

Upgrading firmware can be a pain. It took me 10 hours to go through the whole process
but it was worth it. The firmware upgrade left me with a better web page interface
and the time and year feature now has a drop down that will go many years in advance.

My wireless was good before but after the firmware upgrade it seems to be better.

Its not that difficult to upgrade firmware, but like a lot of home users, its not something 
we do that often so it can be time consuming process.